# temporarily alter SeaMonkey chrome attributes on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, css, gecko, seamonkey

I don't like that the ***Session Restore*** page in *Mozilla SeaMonkey* appears to specify a very short height, making it impossible to examine what sorts of windows are actually up for restore.

I have tracked it down to `aboutSessionRestore.css` having a `height: 12em;` on `#tabList`:

- http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/suite/common/aboutSessionRestore.xhtml
- http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/suite/themes/modern/communicator/aboutSessionRestore.css

Is there a way to quickly fix this though JavaScript or some kind of console, without editing the underlying file in `extensions/modern@themes.mozilla.org.xpi`?

I've tried using my usual `test stylesheet` and `edit stylesheet` [bookmarklets](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html), but it looks like the `chrome` pages are special, and the bookmarklets don't even execute at all whilst on a page like `about:sessionrestore`.